Typescript Compiler API does not support bundling?
I'm trying to build a web page(working on any browser) that generate bundled js file to open in new browser window from given typescript source files.
I searched that the Typescript Compiler API can handle such things, but it has no comment about bundling.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API
Is it true that Typesciprt Compiler API doesn't support bundling?
Should I use esbuild-wasm...? or.. is there any other solution?

TypeScript doesn't provide bundling functionality, whether by API or by tsc
